# Laravel (Carbon) display date difference only in days

Tags: php, date, laravel

How to display diffrence only by days. 
Here `$price->created_at = 2014-04-28`

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($price->created_at))->diffForHumans()
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly you expect and difference to what?

Comment: for example '2 days ago'. But if i just created new resource, the message is - '1 hour ago' (but i need 'today').

Comment: if you add the line " 'Carbon' => 'Carbon\Carbon', " to the bottom of the 'aliases' array in app/config/app.php this will make the carbon library available everywhere in laravel and you will only need to use the code 'carbon::' to create a carbon object

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Suppose you want difference to now() and result from diffForHumans suits you except for today:

```
$created = new Carbon($price->created_at);
$now = Carbon::now();
$difference = ($created->diff($now)->days < 1)
    ? 'today'
    : $created->diffForHumans($now);
```

edit: no need to call Carbon::now() twice so use $now instead.

Comment: created_at is already a Carbon instance with the latest versions of Laravel.

Comment: @KierBorromeo You are right about default behaviour of the Eloquent timestamps, but read the question again. OP doesn't seem to be using it, so that's not the case here.

Comment: Yes, but I was simply suggesting a refactor to shorten and clean the code.

Answer (score 39):

diffInDays function would help.

```
$cDate = Carbon::parse($date);
return $cDate->diffInDays();
```

Comment: Note that diffInDays() will not take YEAR into consideration. For example,  2015-01-01 and 2016-01-02 have only 1 day in difference.

Comment: @abdullahkahraman You are right. Sorry for the confusion. While I was doing the testing, some other issues were affecting my results. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 9):

```
$DeferenceInDays = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now())->diffInDays($dataToCompare);
```

this is the best one try this

Comment: nice and easy for me

Answer (score 1):

When comparing a value in the past to default now:
1 hour ago,
5 months ago

When comparing a value in the future to default now:
1 hour from now,
5 months from now

When comparing a value in the past to another value:
1 hour before,
5 months before

When comparing a value in the future to another value:
1 hour after,
5 months after

```
$dt     = Carbon::now();
$past   = $dt->subMonth();
$future = $dt->addMonth();

echo $dt->subDays(10)->diffForHumans();     // 10 days ago
echo $dt->diffForHumans($past);             // 1 month ago
echo $dt->diffForHumans($future);           // 1 month before
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use **startOfDay()** function

for example :

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$now = $now->startOfDay();
```

that's it!