# insert result from a function in a loop

Tags: php, laravel

I need to calculate the difference between a date in a column from a query and today, inside of a loop, to gather the age of a shipment

I tried using datediff with the date of shipping as first parameter and today() as second

```
@foreach($shipments as $shipment)
    <tr>
        <td data-title="id">{{$shipment->id}}</td>
        <td class=tracking data-title="tracking">{{$shipment->tracking}}</td>
        <td data-title="PartNumber">{{$shipment->PartNumber}}</td>
        <td data-title="DateShipped">{{$shipment->DateShipped}}</td>
        <td data-title="age" value={{$shipment->DateShipped}}-today()><?php echo date_diff({{$shipment->DateShipped}},today())?></td>
        <td data-title="Qtyorder">{{$shipment->Qtyorder}}</td>
        <td data-title="QtyShipped">{{$shipment->QtyShipped}}</td>
        <td data-title="QtyBckorder">{{$shipment->QtyBckorder}}</td>
        <td data-title="purchaseOrder">{{$shipment->purchaseOrder}}</td>
        <td data-title="OrderNumber">{{$shipment->OrderNumber}}</td>
        <td value={{$shipment->Location}}>{{$shipment->Location}}</td>
        <td data-title="paperwork">{{$shipment->paperwork}}</td>
        <td data-title="VMIreceived">{{$shipment->VMIreceived}}</td>
        <td data-title="VMIticketNumber">{{$shipment->VMIticketNumber}}</td>
        <td data-title="VMILRB">{{$shipment->VMILRB}}</td>

        <td><a href="{{ route('shipment.edit',$shipment->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
        <td>
            <form action="{{ route('shipment.destroy', $shipment->id)}}" method="post">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23336817/6945325

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach($shipments as $shipment)
<tr>
    <td  data-title="id">{{$shipment->id}}</td>
    <td class=tracking data-title="tracking">{{$shipment->tracking}}</td>
    <td data-title="PartNumber">{{$shipment->PartNumber}}</td>
    <td data-title="DateShipped">{{$shipment->DateShipped}}</td>
    <td data-title="age" data-value="{{(int) floor((time() - strtotime('2019-04-29')) / (60 * 60 * 24))}}"></td>
    <td data-title="Qtyorder">{{$shipment->Qtyorder}}</td>
    <td data-title="QtyShipped">{{$shipment->QtyShipped}}</td>
    <td data-title="QtyBckorder">{{$shipment->QtyBckorder}}</td>
    <td data-title="purchaseOrder">{{$shipment->purchaseOrder}}</td>
    <td data-title="OrderNumber">{{$shipment->OrderNumber}}</td>
    <td value={{$shipment->Location}}>{{$shipment->Location}}</td>
    <td data-title="paperwork">{{$shipment->paperwork}}</td>
    <td data-title="VMIreceived">{{$shipment->VMIreceived}}</td>
    <td data-title="VMIticketNumber">{{$shipment->VMIticketNumber}}</td>
    <td data-title="VMILRB">{{$shipment->VMILRB}}</td>

    <td><a href="{{ route('shipment.edit',$shipment->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
    <td>
        <form action="{{ route('shipment.destroy', $shipment->id)}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

It will give you difference in days (for example for 24-48 hours it will show 1 day, 48-72, will show 2 days)

`(60 * 60 * 24)` This is the `minute` * `second` * `day`, 
If you want to show diff in hours for example remove `day` and you will get difference in hours (60 * 60 instead of 60 * 60 * 24)

Comment: If it is worked, Hit that this answer is Correct :)

Comment: now i modified you answer to use the value form the previous cell, this is exactly what i wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

Carbon supports a [human readable difference](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff):

```
<td>{{ $shipment->DateShipped->diffForHumans() }}</td>
```