# Exclude "weeks" from Carbon human readable date difference

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I use Carbon with Laravel for date manipulations and display. I can get the difference between a given date and current time using

```
$date->diffForHumans()
```

But my problem is I want everything less than a month to be shown as days and exclude showing "weeks". For example 29 days is shown as 4 weeks 1 day by Carbon, but I want it to be shown as 29 days. It is fine for me if it shows 30 days as 1 month but I do not want "weeks".

Is there a way to do it? Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336261/laravel-carbon-display-date-difference-only-in-days

Comment: I saw that already. I don't want days only, I want minutes, hours, days, months and years and only need to exclude weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/2465

```
$date->diffForHumans([
    'parts'       => 4,
    'skip'        => ['week'],
    'minimumUnit' => 'minute',
]);
```

Comment: I have chosen this answer since it is the only way to do what I want. But I had to resort to writing my own code to do this, as the Carbon version I am using right now don't support this.

Comment: Upgrading the stack is painful, but building new features with old packages versions is worse. Upgrade. ;)